# Breaking from for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, callback

I'm trying to make a function so you can loop through a big object with a lot of objects in them and find a specific method by value. I want to stop the loop in the function when the value is found by using a break statement. This is my code.

```
let fake_window = {
    aaa: "aaa",
    bbb: "bbb",
    ccc: "ccc",
    ddd: function ddd() {
        console.log('ddd');
    },
    eee: {
        eea: "eea",
        eeb: "eeb",
        eec: "eec"
    },
    fff: {
        ffa: "ffa",
        ffb: "ffb",
        ffc: {
            fac: "fac",
            fbc: "fbc",
            fcc: "fcc",
            fdc: "fdc"
        }
    },
    ggg: {
        gga: {
            gaa: "gaa",
            gba: "gba"
        },
        ggb: "ggb"
    }

};

const window_loop = function (window_obj, value) {
    for (const prop in window_obj) {
        if (window_obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            if (value) {
                if (value === window_obj[prop]) { // when value is found
                    console.log("FOUND, NOW STOP!");
                    break;
                }
            }
            console.log(prop + ' => ' + window_obj[prop]);
            if (typeof window_obj[prop] === "object") {
                window_loop(window_obj[prop], value);
            }
        }
    }
};

window_loop(fake_window, 'fbc');
```

When the value is found, I console "FOUND, NOW STOP!" and then I break the loop. But for some reason, the loop keep iterating. Can someone help me with why this is happening?

Comment: `window_loop(fake_window, 'fbc')` calls `window_loop(fake_window['fff'], 'fbc')` calls `window_loop(fake_window['fff']['ffc'], 'fbc')`. Only the last one will break.

Comment: I have added code to show how with minimal changes you can still use your original approach as well.

Comment: @gurvinder372 Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that `fbc` value is reached when `window_loop` is invoked recursively and `window_loop`'s return value is not used to break the outer loop.

You can some changes in your `window_loop` method (*comments inline*)

```
window_loop = function (window_obj, value) {
    var isFound = false; //new flag is introduced
    for (const prop in window_obj) {
        if (window_obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            if (value) {
                if (value === window_obj[prop]) { // when value is found
                    console.log("FOUND, NOW STOP!");
                    isFound = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            console.log(prop + ' => ' + window_obj[prop]);
            if (typeof window_obj[prop] === "object") {
                isFound = window_loop(window_obj[prop], value);
                if ( isFound ) //break when returned value from loop is true
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return isFound; //return this value 
};
```

Another concise approach is

```
var window_loop = function (window_obj, value) {
    //return the value of find
    return Object.keys( window_obj ).find( function( key ){
       if (typeof window_obj[key] === "object") {
            //invoke window_loop recursively if the value is object.
            return window_loop(window_obj[key], value);
       }
       if ( value == key )
       {
           console.log("FOUND, NOW STOP!", key);
       }
       else 
       {
           console.log("Not FOUND, continue !", key);
       }
       return value == key;
    })    
};
```

**Demo**

```js
var fake_window = {
    aaa: "aaa",
    bbb: "bbb",
    ccc: "ccc",
    ddd: function ddd() {
        console.log('ddd');
    },
    eee: {
        eea: "eea",
        eeb: "eeb",
        eec: "eec"
    },
    fff: {
        ffa: "ffa",
        ffb: "ffb",
        ffc: {
            fac: "fac",
            fbc: "fbc",
            fcc: "fcc",
            fdc: "fdc"
        }
    },
    ggg: {
        gga: {
            gaa: "gaa",
            gba: "gba"
        },
        ggb: "ggb"
    }

};

var window_loop = function (window_obj, value) {
    return Object.keys( window_obj ).find( function( key ){
       if (typeof window_obj[key] === "object") {
            return window_loop(window_obj[key], value);
       }
       if ( value == key )
       {
           console.log("FOUND, NOW STOP!", key);
       }
       else 
       {
           console.log("Not FOUND, continue !", key);
       }
       return value == key;
    })    
};

window_loop(fake_window, 'fbc');
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following code snippet :

```js
var pre = document.getElementById("trace");

f(0, "root", {
  a: { aa: "aa", ab: "ab", ac: "ac" },
  b: { ba: "ba", bb: "bb", bc: "bc" }
});

function f(depth, name, tree) {
  log(depth, "call f on \"" + name + "\"");
  log(depth + 1, "for each child of \"" + name + "\"");
  for (let name in tree) {
    log(depth + 2, "child \"" + name + "\"");
    if (!isLeaf(tree[name])) {
      log(depth + 2, "if child is not a leaf");
      f(depth + 3, name, tree[name]);
    } else if (name === "aa") {
      log(depth + 2, "if child is \"aa\"");
      log(depth + 3, color("red", "break"));
      break;
    }
  }
}

function isLeaf(node) {
  return node.hasOwnProperty("length");
}

function color(c, s) {
  return "<span style=\"color:" + c + "\">" + s + "</span>";
}

function log(depth, line) {
  for (let i = 0; i < depth; i++) {
    if ((i + 2) % 3 === 0) {
      pre.innerHTML += color("red", "| ");
    } else if ((i + 1) % 3 === 0) {
      pre.innerHTML += color("gray", "| ");
    } else {
      pre.innerHTML += color("blue", "| ");
    }
  }
  pre.innerHTML += line + "\n";
}
```

```css
pre{font-family:Consolas,Menlo,Monaco,Lucida Console,Liberation Mono,DejaVu Sans Mono,Bitstream Vera Sans Mono,Courier New,monospace,sans-serif;font-size:12px;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;margin:0}
#trace{padding-left:12px;border-left:12px solid #ddd;margin-left:12px}
```

```html
<pre>
function f(depth, name, tree) {
  for (let name in tree) {
    if (!isLeaf(tree[name])) {
      f(depth + 3, name, tree[name]);
    } else if (name === "aa") {
      break;
    }
  }
}

f(0, "root", {
  a: { aa: "aa", ab: "ab", ac: "ac" },
  b: { ba: "ba", bb: "bb", bc: "bc" }
});
</pre><pre id="trace"></pre>
```

The right part of the output is a trace of execution. Here is how to read it :

- Each horizontal line is an event.
- Events are sorted in ascending chronological order.
- A vertical line is a scope, i.e. a pair of curly brackets.
- The length of a vertical line is the life span of a scope.
- A blue vertical line is a function scope.
- A red vertical line is a `for` loop scope.

What you need to know is that the `break` statement has no effect on the left side of the closest red line, in technical words, it has no effect outside the `for` loop scope. Based on this information you should be able to figure out what's happening by yourself.

I hope you won't blame me for trying an original approach :-)